# how to retrieve count of different object types from JSON string in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I have a single array json string containing data:

```
[{"Name":"John","Age":"22"}, {"Name":"Jack","Age":"56"}, {"Name":"John","Age":"82"}, {"Name":"Jack","Age":"95"}]
```

I have deserialized the data and have successfully written the data to jquery datatables. However i would now like to add a column in the datatable to contain the count of names that are john and names that are jack all in one column. I can get the individual counts by saying the following in a loop:

```
if (people[i].Name == "John")
   {
                name_count++;
   }
if (people[i].Name == "Jack")
   {
          name_count2++;
   }
```

How do i get this data to display in One Column that matches either the row containing the name jack or john? I am using C#. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some linq grouping against the array

```
    var peeps = from person in people 
        group person by person.name into bucket 
        select new { name = bucket.Key, count = bucket.Count() };
```

This will create an enumerable anonymous type with name and count properties that you can iterate over to get the name and count of the names, e.g. :

```
class Guy
    {
        public int age; public string name;
        public Guy( int age, string name ) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            var GuyArray = new Guy[] { 
            new Guy(22,"John"),new Guy(25,"John"),new Guy(27,"John"),new Guy(29,"John"),new Guy(12,"Jack"),new Guy(32,"Jack"),new Guy(52,"Jack"),new Guy(100,"Abe")};

        var peeps = from f in GuyArray group f by f.name into g select new { name = g.Key, count = g.Count() };

            foreach ( var record in peeps ) {
                Console.WriteLine( record.name + " : " + record.count );
            }

        }
    }
```

Will emit:

```
John : 4
Jack : 3
Abe : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using underscore.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore). You can easily achieve any sort of map/reduce/select you want. Here an example:

```
var people = [{"Name":"John","Age":"22"}, {"Name":"Jack","Age":"56"}, {"Name":"John","Age":"82"}, {"Name":"Jack","Age":"95"}];

var num_johns = _(people).select(function(obj){ 
    return obj.Name === 'John'}).length;

alert(num_johns); //alerts 2
```

You can even go a step further and factor out the select function with some currying http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/ - depends on what your exact problem is.

Comment: thanks for the reply. However I  am looking for a c# solution. I actually have a copy of my program thats fully functional with the correct results using client side code. Due to the amount of rprocessing however it has now become extremely slow and need an alternative solution in C#.